# Binary version of CSV

Tags: csv, file-format

I want to ask about a file format which becomes handy for data recording.

For example, I have to record trajectory data and the data would be like this.

```
t, x, y, z
0.001, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3
0.002, 0.11, 0.19, 0.31
0.003, 0.13, 0.16, 0.35
```

Actually, I searched about file format and found that the above file format is called as **csv(Comma Separated Values)**.

As csv records data as pure text, the data is easily readable by human.

But sometime it requires long digits to record data(ie. 15931548831, 1248.128657).

And the more long digits are required, the more time is required to write file.

For this reason, I need a file format satisfying the following conditions.

- Data should or could be recorded in pure binary
- Meta data(ie. data name, recorded date) should be included in file.

Do you know anyone?

Thank you.

Comment: protobuf seems pretty obvious of a choice. BSON if performance isn't really that important and you're mostly recording numbers.

Comment: CSV is definitely not the right place to start for storing binary data.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, Thanks. I'll check protobuf. And in my case the codes run with 1kHz~, so the performance is crucial.

Comment: @tangrs Yes. I just wanted to say that I've happened to know I had used CSV. :D

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [Scientific data exchange format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats#Scientific_data_(data_exchange)), since this kind of data are typical to computational science.

You certainly want to adopt a *file standard* since CSV is popular for being able to be read and written with many different tools. One popular choice is the *[HDF5 file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format)*. There exist HDF5 library for any popular programming languages. HDF5 performs especially well at storing (many *n*-dimensional) tables and associated metadata.

Another typical choice some people do is serialization as binary floating point numbers. In C++, this would be archived as (source: [a C++ forum](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/56985/))

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  float f1 = -187.33667, f2 = 0.0;
  std::ofstream out("test.bin",std::ios_base::binary);
  if(out.good())
  {
    std::cout << "Writing floating point number: " << std::fixed << f1 << std::endl;
    out.write((char *)&f1,sizeof(float));
    out.close();
  }
  std::ifstream in("test.bin",std::ios_base::binary);
  if(in.good())
  {
    in.read((char *)&f2,sizeof(float));
    std::cout << "Reading floating point number: " << std::fixed << f2 << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In this particular example, really *binary* data are written:

```
$ hexdump test.bin 
0000000 5630 c33b
```

As you see, the file requires *4 bytes* of storage instead of 11 bytes (11 characters) as would be needded when storing the ASCII characters `-187.33667`. With this concept (a *custom* reader and writer) you can also store tables of number efficiently, and of course this is how file formats like HDF5 work under the hood.

There are scientific code which implement custom file formats like this, but I strongly discourage from adopting custom file formats because they are error prone, hard to debug, inspect and time consuming in terms of writing the tooling.